# How to configure SysCache in own config file?

Tags: nhibernate

My asp.net application have two config files: web.config and hibernate.config.
When I add SysCache section in web.config it works, but in hibernate.config doesn't. I need in hibernate.config. Is it possible?

Comment: Why -1? What's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the standard `configSource` attribute to put the settings in a separate file.

`hibernate.config` is not extensible.